# Как скомбинировать listbox

Tags: c#

Есть:
listbox1, в нём: 123, abc
listbox2 в нём: 987, zxc
Нужно в listbox3 скомбинировать: 123987, 123zxc, abc987, abczxc.
Есть код, но он подряд в listbox комбинирует, а нужно построчно

```
string result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < listBox2.Items.Count; j++)
        result += $"{listBox1.Items[i]}{listBox2.Items[j]}";
result = result.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',', ' ' });
listBox3.Items.Add(result);
```

Comment: [Прямое произведение множеств](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//listBox1.Items = 123, abc
//listBox2.Items = 987, zxc
//listBox3.Items = 1[0]2[0], 1[0]2[1], 1[1]2[0], 1[1]2[1]
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < listBox2.Items.Count; j++)
        listBox3.Items.Add(listBox1[i] + listBox12[j]);
```